# How to set GeometryReader height according to its children height in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI application, I have a VStack (VStack 1) container that get full screen height. Inside this VStack, I have an other VStack (VStack 2) that get height according to its childrens (Text), and I want to put it at the bottom of this parent (VStack 1). On the VStack 2, I need to put a GeometryReader to get the height of VStack (VStack 2). The problem is that the GeometryReader get automaticaly full screen height. So the VStack 2 is placed on the middle of the screen. It's not that I want. I don't know if I can set the height of the GeometryReader with the same height of the VStack 2?

My test code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
           Text("Text n°1")
           Text("Text n°2")
           Text("Text n°3")
           Text("Text n°4")
        }
        .border(Color(.red))
      }
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: nil, alignment: .bottom)
      .border(Color(.black))
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

That I want:

[image: Result I need]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Following is to set child view height to parent view when using GeometryReader

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var totalHeight = CGFloat(100) // no matter - just for static Preview !!
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment:.top) {
            Text("Title 1")
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text("Subtitle 1")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    Text("Subtitle 2")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    Text("Subtitle 3")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                .background(GeometryReader {gp -> Color in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // update on next cycle with calculated height of ZStack !!!
                        self.totalHeight = gp.size.height
                    }
                    return Color.clear
                })
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: totalHeight)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61315678/815864

Comment: Will `DispatchQueue.main.async` cause a drawing loop?

Answer (score -2):

I think you're overcomplicating it by using a `GeometryReader`. Have you tried just using a `Spacer()`?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Haha")
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use `GeometryReader` to get the height value of the second `VStack`